# How to delete string from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, split, strip

This can look like a simple question but not in my situation.

I have a list

```
list0 = ['amigohello','amigobye']
```

And i want to delete "amigo" from it.
If I try:

```
for x in list0:
    print x.split("amigo")
```

It gives me next:

```
['', 'hello']
['', 'bye']
```

I tried:

```
for x in list0:
    x = str(x.split("amigo"))
    print x.split("[''")
```

Also:

```
for x in list0:
    print x.strip('amigo')
```

And it gives me:

```
hell
bye
```

The most strange is that in this output doesnt delete all 'o' if i change 'amigohello' to 'amigohoeollo'

And of course i tried with x.strip('amigo')[0]

What i just want to do is delete exactly on string everything that is "amigo", not a.m.i.g.o or ami.go., only if i found amigo without the [] problem or a solution to the [] problem. Thanks.

Comment: `.split()` is based on a delimiter. This is usually a whitespace character. So if you did `"amigohello".split('g')` you'd get `["ami", "ohello"]`

Answer (score 6):

You should use `str.replace` to replace *exact* appearances of the word `amigo`:

```
for x in list0:
    print x.replace("amigo", "")
```

---

```
'hello'
'bye'
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a `replace` method in which you can replace the undesired word for an empty string.

```
list0 = ['amigohello','amigobye']
for x in list0:
    print(x.replace("amigo", ""))  # hello, bye
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list0 = [item.replace('amigo','') for item in list0]
```